# Let's draw the flag of Nepal

Tags: popularity-contest, ascii-art, graphical-output, kolmogorov-complexity, geometry

Nepal’s flag ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nepalese_Flag), [Numberphile](http://www.numberphile.com/videos/nepal_flag.html)) looks very different from any other. It also has specific drawing instructions (included in the Wikipedia article). I want you guys to make a program which will draw the flag of Nepal.

The user inputs the requested height of the flag (from 100 to 10000 pixels) and the program outputs the flag of Nepal. You can choose any way to draw the flag: everything from ASCII art to OpenGL.

This is a popularity contest, so the winner will be the highest voted answer on the 1st of February, so don’t worry about length of code, but remember that shorter code may get more up-votes.

There is only one requirement: you are not allowed to use web resources.

Have fun :)

[image: image of the flag of Nepal from Wikimedia Commons]

Comment: Deja vu! Also, how many rows of ASCII text are in 100px?

Comment: @KendallFrey Well, ASCII art is one of the ways, to solve this, however there is no answer into your question. as it depends on font size and spacing between lines, answer provider should count it himself.

Comment: In that case, surely `print("|\\\n|\\")` is a valid solution. I think you need to be more specific about the rules for non-bitmap entries.

Comment: **User inputs height of flag** that means that generated output if input is 100 and output of 101 should differ, so answer should contain something like `GetTextExtentPoint32` to measure output

Comment: Please do not delete and repost your question. There's editing for a reason... also, there's no link in your new question.

Comment: @ST3 For ascii output, I recommend saying that each character is a pixel. It makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Also, rather than disallowing internet resources, why not require that the flag actually be drawn (ie created by code)?

Comment: I got a filling there is language that makes it pretty straightforward to code those drawing instructions. [ContextFree](http://www.contextfreeart.org/mediawiki/index.php/Context_Free_Art:About) first comes to mind. Looking forward to it.

Comment: what about a `data:` url? =p

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## SVG, <del>1375</del>, <del>1262</del>, <del>1036</del>, <del>999</del>, <del>943</del>, 939

```
<svg>
<defs>
<style>.w{fill:white}</style>
<g id="f"><path d="M1,1L1,20L18,20L6,10L17,10z" style="stroke:#003893;fill:#dc143c"/></g>
<g id="m"><polygon points="1,0 -.5,.86 -.5,-.86"/></g>
<g id="b"><polygon points="1,0 -.5,.86 -.5,-.86"/><polygon points="1,0 -.5,.86 -.5,-.86"transform="rotate(32)"/></g>
<g id="t"><use xlink:href="#b"/><use xlink:href="#b"transform="rotate(60)"/></g>
<g id="s">
<use xlink:href="#m"/>
<use xlink:href="#m"transform="rotate(20)"/>
<use xlink:href="#m"transform="rotate(45)"/>
<use xlink:href="#m"transform="rotate(70)"/>
<use xlink:href="#m"transform="rotate(90)"/>
</g>
</defs>
<g transform="scale(.7)">
<use xlink:href="#f" x="5" y="6"transform="scale(19,23)"/>
<use xlink:href="#t" x="2.8" y="7"class="w"transform="scale(70)"/>
<path d="M157,292 A 40,35 0 1 0 237,292 43,45 0 1 1 157,292z"class="w"/>
<use xlink:href="#s" x="5.6" y="8.9"class="w"transform="scale(35)"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

[image: Chrome rendering]

SVG doesn't really have user input, AFAIK, so you can change the scale modifying this line:

> `<g transform="scale(.7)">`

Comment: There should be exactly 8 triangles in the Moon and 12 in the Sun. But you got 11 and 15.

Comment: should be fixed.

Comment: It does have user input. By pressing CTRL + + or CTRL + - the user can change the scale in many web browsers.

Comment: This is 918 bytes long (you can use Unix line endings instead of Windows to save a byte per line break). And while we're at that topic, you can just drop line breaks altogether to bring it to 897. *But* this doesn't render at all in either IE, Chrome, Firefox or Inkscape for me. At least not as a standalone SVG. Only when embedded in HTML (but that brings it to 960 bytes). Fixing the XML errors brings the file to 1008 bytes. I'll golf it down a bit.

Comment: http://hypftier.de/temp/svg.7z is a Mercurial repository with the changes I made. You can inspect the messages easiest with `hg log --style=changelog -r 0..tip`. I might do a more detailed writeup of the techniques I used there.

Answer (score 27):

## JavaScript, <strike>569</strike> <strike>537</strike> <strike>495</strike> 442 characters (ASCII)

```
h="";M=Math;Z=M.max;Y=M.min;function d(a,b,r,s,t){n=M.sqrt(a*a+e*e);return n-(r+M.abs((M.atan2(a,e
)/M.PI*b+t)%1-0.5)*s*n)}f=parseInt(prompt(),10);for(g=0;g<f;g++){for(k=0;k<2*f;k++)e=k/(0.5*f)-0.8
,q=g/(0.25*f),u=q-1.08,v=q-1.29,z=e*e+u*u-0.3364,E=Z(-e-0.8,Y(Z(0.62*e+0.8-q,-2.06+q),Z(1*e+0.8+
0.85-q,-3.87+q))),p=0>Y(d(q-2.91,6,0.38,0.7,10),Y(Z(e*e+v*v-0.3025,-z),Z(d(q-1.54,8,0.25,0.6,10.5)
,q-1.7)))?" ":-0.13>E?";":0>=E?"8":"",h+=p;h+="\n"}h
```

To run : copy-paste to browser console (eg: Chrome developer tools or Firebug)

Result :

```
8 
8888 
8888888 
8888;88888 
8888;;;;88888 
8888;;;;;;;888888 
8888;;;;;;;;;;;88888 
8888;;;;;;;;;;;;;;88888 
8888;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;88888 
8888;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;888888 
8888;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;88888 
8888;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;88888 
8888;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;88888 
8888;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;88888 
8888;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;888888 
8888;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;88888 
8888;;;;;;;;;;;; ;  ;  ; ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;88888 
8888;;; ;;;;;               ;;;;; ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;88888 
8888;;;  ;;;;;;           ;;;;;;  ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;888888 
8888;;;;   ;;;             ;;;   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;88888 
8888;;;;;                       ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;88888 
8888;;;;;;;                   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;88888 
8888;;;;;;;;;               ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;88888 
8888;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;888888 
8888;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;88888 
8888;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888 
8888;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;888 
8888;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;888 
8888;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;888 
8888;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;888 
8888;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;888 
8888;;;;;;;;;   ;;;   ;;;   ;;;;;;;;;;888 
8888;;;;;;;;;;             ;;;;;;;;;;;;;888 
8888;;;;                         ;;;;;;;;;888 
8888;;;;;;                     ;;;;;;;;;;;;;888 
8888;;;;;;;                   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;888 
8888;;;                           ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;888 
8888;;;;;                       ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;888 
8888;;;;;;;                   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;888 
8888;;;;;                       ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;888 
8888;;;; ;;;;;             ;;;;; ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;888 
8888;;;;;;;;;               ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;888 
8888;;;;;;;;;  ;;;;   ;;;;  ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;888 
8888;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;888 
8888;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;888 
8888;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;888 
8888;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;888 
8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888 
888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
```

---

EDIT : added height as user input as ST3 suggested. it works best with big values (eg : 120)

Comment: Well, looks good, but where is user input? It is one of requirements.

Comment: I didn't know that (or at least didnt read it :)). I have updated answer.

Comment: Your Moon features 6 triangles. Should have 8. Further, it crashed my browser for large values.

Comment: I revisited whole code. Rendering is now closer to original flag and looks better, especially for low height values (eg : 20 pixels). Moon has been fixed and has the right number of triangles (the star was too low to view all of them). Recommanded height value is "100".

Comment: Crazy excellent submission.

Answer (score 22):

## Mathematica

Nepal's Interim Constitution - Schedule 1 (rel. to Article 6), pp. 260 and 262, provides 25 detailed instructions about how to construct the flag. (see http://www.ccd.org.np/resources/interim.pdf). The numbers in the comments refer to the corresponding instructions in the constitution.

We will need functions to draw equilateral triangles and determine the distance from a point to a line:

```
ClearAll[triangle]
triangle[a_?NumericQ,b_?NumericQ,c_?NumericQ,labeled_:True]:=
Block[{x,y,pt,sqr},sqr=#.#&;
pt[a1_,b1_,c1_]:=Reduce[sqr[{x,y}]==b1^2&&sqr[{x,y}-{a1,0}]==c1^2&&y>0,{x,y}];
{(
(*Polygon[{{0,0},{a,0},{x,y}}]*)
Polygon[{{-a/2(*0*),0},{a/2,0},{x-a/2,y}}]),
If[labeled,
{Text[Style[Framed[a,Background->LightYellow],11],{a/2,0}],
Text[Style[Framed[b,Background->LightYellow],11],{x/2,y/2}],
Text[Style[Framed[c,Background->LightYellow],11],{(a+x)/2,y/2}]},{}]}/.ToRules[pt[a,b,c]]]

(*distance from point to a line *)
dist[line_,{x0_,y0_}]:=(Abs[a x0+b y0+c]/.{x0-> m[[1]],y0-> m[[2]]})/Sqrt[a^2+b^2]; (* used below *)
```

The remaining code, with numbers referring to the instructions. By far, the most challenging part is to make the rays for the moon and the sun.  `GeometricalTransformation` comes in handy for doing translations and rotations.

```
    (*shape inside flag*)
(*1*)
w=100;a={0,0};b={w,0};
lAB=Line[{a,b}];
tA=Text["A",Offset[{-10,-20},a]];
tB=Text["B",Offset[{20,-20},b]];

(*2*)
c={0,w 4/3};d={0,w};
lAC=Line[{a,c}];
tC=Text["C",Offset[{-10,20},c]];
lAD=Line[{a,d}];
tD=Text["D",Offset[{-10,0},d]];
lBD=Line[{b,d}];

(*3*)
e=Solve[(x-w)^2+y^2==(w)^2&&y==w-x,{x,y}][[1,All,2]];
tE=Text["E",Offset[{15,0},e]];

(*4*)
f={0,e[[2]]};tF=Text["F",Offset[{-10,0},f]];
g={w,e[[2]]};tG=Text["G",Offset[{15,0},g]];
lFG=Line[{f,g}];
poly={a,b,e,g,c};

(*5*)lCG= Line[{c,g}];

(*moon*)
(*6*)
lineCG=N[((f[[2]]-c[[2]])/w)x+c[[2]](*100*)];
h={w/4,0};tH=Text["H",Offset[{0,-20},h]];
i={h[[1]],lineCG/.x->h[[1]]};tI=Text["I",Offset[{10,0},i]];
lHI={Dashed, LightGray,Line[{h,i}]};

(*7*)
j={0,f[[2]]+(c[[2]]-f[[2]])/2};tJ=Text["J",Offset[{-10,10},j]];
lineJG=N[((f[[2]]-j[[2]])/g[[1]])x+j[[2]]];
k={Solve[lineCG==j[[2]],x][[1,1,2]],j[[2]]};tK=Text["K",Offset[{10,10},k]];
(*k={Solve[lineCG\[Equal]c[[2]],x][[1,1,2]],j[[2]]};tK=Text["K",Offset[{10,10},k]];*)
lJK={Dashed, LightGray,Line[{j,k}]};

(*8*)l={i[[1]],j[[2]]};tL=Text["L",Offset[{0,10},l]];
(*9*)lJG={LightGray,Dashed,Line[{j,g}]};
(*10*)m={h[[1]],(lineJG/.x-> h[[1]])};tM=Text["M",Offset[{0,10},m]];
(*11*)distMfromBD=dist[{1,1,-w(*100*)},m];
 n={i[[1]],m[[2]]-distMfromBD};tN=Text["N",Offset[{0,0},n]];
(*ln=Abs[l[[2]]-n[[2]]];*)
(*12*)o={0,m[[2]]};tO=Text["O",Offset[{-10,0},o]];
lM={Dashed,LightGray,Line[{o,{g[[1]],o[[2]]}}]};

(*13*)
radiusLN=l[[2]]-n[[2]];
p={m[[1]]-radiusLN,m[[2]]};tP=Text["P",Offset[{0,10},p]];
q={m[[1]]+radiusLN,m[[2]]};tQ=Text["Q",Offset[{0,10},q]];
moonUpperEdge={White,Circle[l,radiusLN,{Pi,2 Pi}]};
moonLowerEdge={White,Circle[m,radiusMQ,{Pi,2 Pi}]};


(*14*)radiusMQ=q[[1]]-m[[1]];


(*15*)radiusNM=m[[2]]-n[[2]];
arc={Yellow,Circle[n,radiusNM,{Pi/7,6 Pi/7}]};
{r,s}=Solve[(x-l[[1]])^2+(y-l[[2]])^2==(radiusLN)^2 &&(x-n[[1]])^2+(y-n[[2]])^2==(radiusNM)^2,{x,y}][[All,All,2]];
tR=Text["R",Offset[{0,0},r]];
tS=Text["S",Offset[{0,0},s]];
t={h[[1]],r[[2]]};
tT={Black,Text["T",Offset[{0,0},t]]};


(*16*)radiusTS=Abs[t[[1]]-s[[1]]];
(*17*)radiusTM=Abs[t[[2]]-m[[2]]];

(*18 triangles*)
t2=Table[GeometricTransformation[GeometricTransformation[triangle[4,4,4,False][[1]],RotationTransform[k Pi/8]],{TranslationTransform[t]}],{k,-4,3}];
midRadius=(Abs[radiusTM+radiusTS]/2-2);
pos=1;table2=GeometricTransformation[t2[[pos++]],{TranslationTransform[#]}]&/@Table[midRadius {Cos@t,Sin[t]},{t,Pi/16,15 Pi/16,\[Pi]/8}];

(*19 sun*)u={0,f[[2]]/2};tU=Text["U",Offset[{-10,0},u]];
lineBD=N[(d[[2]]/w)x+d[[2]]];
v={-Solve[lineBD==u[[2]],x][[1,1,2]],u[[2]]};tV=Text["V",Offset[{10,0},v]];
lUV={LightGray,Dashed,Line[{u,v}]};

(*20*)w={h[[1]],u[[2]]};tW={Black,Text["W",Offset[{0,0},w]]};
(*21*)
(*22*)

t3=Table[GeometricTransformation[GeometricTransformation[triangle[9,9,9,False][[1]],RotationTransform[k Pi/6]],{TranslationTransform[w]}],{k,-3,9}];
midRadius3=(Abs[radiusTM+radiusTS]/2+2.5);
pos=1;
table3=GeometricTransformation[t3[[pos++]],{TranslationTransform[#]}]&/@Table[midRadius3 {Cos@t,Sin[t]},{t,0,2 Pi,2\[Pi]/12}];



Show[
Graphics[{Gray,
(*1*)lAB,tA,tB,
(*2*)lAC,tC,lAD,tD,lBD,
(*3*)tE,
(*4*)tF,lFG,tG,{Red,Opacity[.4],Polygon[poly]},
(*5*)lCG,
(*6*)tH,lCG,tI,lHI,
(*7*)tJ,lJK,tK,
(*8*)tL,
(*9*)lJG,
(*10*)tM,
(*11*)tN,
(*12*)lM,tO,
(*13*)moonUpperEdge,tP,tQ,
(*14*)moonLowerEdge,
(*15*)arc,tR,tS,tT,
(*16*){White,Dashed,Circle[t,radiusTS(*,{0, Pi}*)]},

(*17*){White,Opacity[.5],Disk[t,radiusTM,{0, 2 Pi}]},
(*18 triangles*){White,(*EdgeForm[Black],*)table2},
(*19 sun*)tU,tV,lUV,

(*20*)tW,{Opacity[.5],White,Disk[w,Abs[m[[2]]-n[[2]]]]},
(*21*)Circle[w,Abs[l[[2]]-n[[2]]]],
(*22*){Black(*White*),EdgeForm[Black],triangle[4,4,4,False](*table3*)},
{White,(*EdgeForm[Black],*)table3},

(*23*)
{Darker@Blue,Thickness[.03],Line[{a,b,e,g,c,a}]}

},
Ticks-> None(*{{0,100},{0,80,120,130}}*), BaseStyle-> 16,AspectRatio-> 1.3,Axes-> True],

(*cresent moon*)
RegionPlot[{(x-25)^2+(y-94.19)^2<21.4^2&&(x-25)^2+(y-102.02)^2>21.4^2},{x,0,100},{y,30,130},PlotStyle->{Red,White}]]
```

The following flag, from the above code, is made according to the instructions in the constitution.

Colors are modified to enable easier viewing of the construction lines.
The letters refer to points and lines in the instructions.

[image: flag construction]

---

By the way, flags of the world can be called up directly within Mathematica.  For example:

```
Graphics[CountryData["Nepal", "Flag"][[1]], ImageSize->{Automatic,200}]
```

[image: Nepal]

Comment: uhm, that's like cheating...

Comment: friol, Yes, I agree. That's why I included a variation.

Comment: IMO this doesn't break the rule, as there are no resources being loaded from the web directly.

Comment: Mathematica always allows ways to cheat.

Comment: @ST3 Mathematica _is_ the cheat.

Comment: Should have 12 triangles in the Sun and 8 in the Moon. You got 9 and 16.

Comment: Victor, I corrected the number of triangles.

Answer (score 9):

## Python

```python
import turtle, sys
from math import sqrt, sin, cos, pi

height = int(sys.argv[1])
width = height / 4 * 3
turtle.screensize(width, height)
t = turtle.Turtle()

# the layout
t.pencolor("#0044cc")
t.fillcolor("#cc2244")
t.pensize(width / 25)
t.pendown()
t.fill(True)
t.forward(width)
t.left(135)
t.forward(width)
t.right(135)
t.forward(width / sqrt(2))
t.right(90)
t.goto(0, height)
t.forward(height)
t.fill(False)
t.penup()

# the bottom star
t.fillcolor("#ffffff")
t.pencolor("#ffffff")
t.pensize(1)
radius = width / 5
x = width / 4
y = height / 4
t.goto(x + radius, y)
t.pendown()
t.fill(True)
for i in range(24):
    t.goto(x + radius * (5 + (-1) ** i) / 6 * cos(i * pi / 12), y + radius * (5 + (-1) ** i) / 6 * sin(i * pi / 12))
t.fill(False)
t.penup()

# the top star
radius = width / 9
x = width / 4
y = height * 2 / 3
t.goto(x + radius, y)
t.pendown()
t.fill(True)
for i in range(28):
    t.goto(x + radius * (6 + (-1) ** i) / 7 * cos(i * pi / 14), y + radius * (6 + (-1) ** i) / 7 * sin(i * pi / 14))
t.fill(False)
t.penup()

# the moon
radius = width / 5
x = width / 4
y = height / sqrt(2)
t.goto(x + radius, y)
t.pendown()
t.fill(True)
for i in range(30):
    t.goto(x + radius * cos(i * pi / 30), y - radius * sin(i * pi / 30))
for i in range(30):
    t.goto(x - radius * cos(i * pi / 30), y - radius / 2 * sin(i * pi / 30))
t.fill(False)
t.penup()
t.hideturtle()

raw_input("press enter")
```

Uses python's Tk turtles, example of `python nepal.py 150` and `python nepal.py 200` respectively:

[image]

Comment: Can you write the number of chars in your sourcecode?

Comment: Why? is this [tag:code-golf]?

Comment: The Moon should feature exactly 8 triangles. Yours has 9 and a half.

Comment: @Victor Fixed. Didn't realize that is a strict requirement

Answer (score 5):

## Python (+PIL), 578

Because I'm quite bored today..

```
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw
from math import*
I,k,l,m,n,o,_=Image.new('P',(394,480)),479,180,465,232,347,255;D=ImageDraw.Draw(I);P,G=D.polygon,D.pieslice
I.putpalette([_,_,_,0,0,_,_,20,60])
def S(x,y,r,e,l,b):
 p,a,h=[],2*pi/e,r*l;c,d=[0,-a/2][b],[a/2,0][b]
 for i in range(e):p+=[(x+r*cos(i*a+c),y+r*sin(i*a+c)),(x+h*cos(i*a+d),y+h*sin(i*a+d))]
 P(p,fill=0)
P([(0,0),(393,246),(144,246),(375,k),(0,k)],fill=1)
P([(14,25),(o,n),(110,n),(o,m),(14,m)],fill=2)
S(96,o,68,12,.6,0)
G([(31,90),(163,221)],0,l,fill=0)
G([(28,68),(166,200)],0,l,fill=2)
S(96,178,40,16,.7,1)
I.show()
```

[image: nepal]

Comment: You have two extra triangles on both the moon and the sun, should be 8 and 10, not 10 and 12 :)

Answer (score 1):

## PostScript

Code:

```postscript
.15 .15 scale            % over-all scale

% draw the red area and blue border
7 7 moveto
360 7 lineto
128 240 lineto
367 240 lineto
7 467 lineto
closepath
gsave                    % save the outline path for further use
.86 .08 .24 setrgbcolor  % crimson red
fill                     % draw the red area
grestore                 % get back the saved outline path
0 .22 .58 setrgbcolor    % dark blue
14 setlinewidth
stroke                   % draw the blue border

1 setgray                % white

% draw the lower sun
96 130 translate         % coordinate origin of sun
69 0 moveto
12 {                     % 12 spikes
  69 0 lineto
  15 rotate
  46 0 lineto
  15 rotate
} repeat
closepath fill

% draw the upper sun
0 167 translate          % coordinate origin at center of sun
29 0 moveto
16 {                     % 16 spikes
  29 0 lineto
  11.25 rotate
  42 0 lineto
  11.25 rotate
} repeat
closepath fill

% draw the crescent moon
0 24 65 180 0 arc        % the lower arc
0 57 72 335 205 arcn     % the upper arc
closepath fill

showpage
```

The flag size can be controlled by specifying
the resolution in the Ghostscript call.

Result (height of flag is 480 pixels, created by `gswin64c -r480 nepal.ps`):

[image]

Result (height of flag is 120 pixels, created by `gswin64c -r120 nepal.ps`):

[image]