# Draw the South Korean flag

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, kolmogorov-complexity, geometry

When I stumbled upon [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18664/lets-draw-flag-of-nepal) I remembered that I had also once seen precise rules for the construction of the South Korean flag. And this is quite a different construction.

[image]

<sup>[Source: Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_South_Korea.svg)</sup>

So you're to draw an exact construction of this one now!

### Specification

You can render the flag to file or screen using vector or raster graphics. If your output is rasterised, your image must have dimensions of 450x300 pixels or more.

All length ratios and positions need to be exactly as shown in the following diagram:

[image]

<sup>[Source: Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_South_Korea_(construction_sheet).svg)</sup>

Note that the centres of the two small circles align with the diagonal.

For the colours, you must use the following palette:

- White: #FFFFFF
- Black: #000000
- Red: #C60C30
- Blue: #003478

The black boundary must not be drawn *unless* your drawing system does not let you specify a 3:2 canvas for technical reasons (otherwise, you should use a 3:2 canvas and the flag should fill all of it). If you do need to add the boundary, it may be arbitrarily thick - the flag should be considered strictly *inside* the black boundary. Any other helping lines or length indicators must not be drawn. I.e., the flag should appear exactly as in the first image.

### Scoring

This is code golf, so the shortest answer (in bytes) wins.

As a word of warning, using existing compression (like embedding a compressed GIF) falls into [several standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/8478).

Comment: Interestingly, the Korean flag contains an early form of the binary number system (http://britton.disted.camosun.bc.ca/jbbinflag.htm)

Comment: Do we have to draw the border when we are using an HTML page bigger than the flag, being white there is no separation visible even if the canvas/element size is similar to the flag

Comment: @Optimizer, no, if the canvas is bounded in a way that can somehow be made visible (e.g. by the highlighting of your browser's "inspect element"), then you don't need a boundary. The black border should only be drawn in the rare case where the extent of the canvas cannot technically be defined.

Comment: I'm assuming `CountryData["ROK","Flag"]` doesn't count?

Comment: [People Confused the South Korean Flag With the Pepsi Logo at the Winter Olympics 2018](https://www.teenvogue.com/story/south-korean-flag-pepsi-logo-olympics-opening-ceremony)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## PHP/HTML/SVG, 324

(line breaks added for legibility)

```
<?=gzinflate(base64_decode('tVHBioMwFPyVwF5WSOzLi/tswQjdu9cevIk1KqtriaFd9utrgpSWFva0PPImMwzDkGTz
uWXnvrl8Tj8aOPAUebLNs5Y5W33PZrKjtpOrXPOuVEy7KMiD54mKMY3yrO5tPTTMaonM9MOg32qCWgHb5Nmpch076kIih/2y
PC4jRRCIU6BhbkwGV7lmAagk3d5nCfwQdKByVBwOFLagQu6exZLNzk5fjU+B9S4u/dF1Gh/apRw6Cb83uzHm0S69/cWbSIkx
YfSf5QT6dkk5UoACIeAfXTftepb/za8='));
```

The compressed data expands to the same SVG data as my earlier answer shown below, but with two changes to aid compression:

1. The two `<use>` sections are expanded to the original content of the `<defs>` section. This makes the source text longer, but reduces the entropy so it compresses better.
2. In the first `<g>` element, I changed `transform=translate(36,24)rotate(33.69)` to `transform=rotate(33.69)translate(43.27)`. This has the same effect geometrically, but compresses better because the sequence `><g transform=rotate(` now appears twice.

By default, PHP will serve this as `Content-Type: text/html`, so the invalid XML syntax shouldn't be a problem.

## SVG/HTML, 463

The HTML parser isn't too fussed about correct syntax, so we can do away with quotation marks in the parameters as long as they don't contain any spaces. It should be possible to squeeze this down further with a bit of Javascript.

```html
<svg viewBox=0,0,72,48><defs><path d=M-25-6V6Zm3,0V6m3,0V-6M19-6V6Zm3,0V6m3,0V-6Z stroke=#000
stroke-width=2 id=p /></defs><g transform=translate(36,24)rotate(33.69)><circle r=12 fill=#c60c30
/><path d=M12,0A12,12,0,0,1-12,0A6,6,0,0,0,0,0A6,6,0,0,1,12,0Z fill=#003478 /><use xlink:href=#p
/><path d=M17,0h10z stroke=#fff stroke-width=1 /><g transform=rotate(112.62)><use xlink:href=#p
/><path d=M-27,0h4Zm6,0h4ZM20,0h4Z stroke=#fff stroke-width=1 /></g></g></svg>
```

Answer (score 45):

### Python + Pycairo, <del>371 370</del> 366 bytes

[image: Flag]

```py
from cairo import*
p=3.141593
c=Context(SVGSurface("F",12,8))
C=c.set_source_rgb;R=c.rectangle;T=c.rotate;F=c.fill
C(1,1,1);R(0,0,12,8);F()
c.translate(6,4);T(.588);b=3188
for o in[(0,.2,.47),(.77,.05,.19)]*2:C(*o);i=b/2%2;b+=1;c.arc(i,0,2-i,0,p+i*p);F();T(p)
C(0,0,0)
for x in(p,1.966)*2:
 for y in.5,0,1:
    for z in-1,1:R(3+y,-z,1./3,z*(2.75+b%2)/3);F()
    b/=2
 T(x)
```

Outputs a tiny SVG file named `F`.

Comment: `C(*[.77,0,.05,.2,.19,.47][i::2])` is shorter than `C(*[(.77,.05,.19),(0,.2,.47)][i%2])`

Comment: Why do you write `s=SVGSurface("F",12,8);c=Context(s)` instead of just `c=Context(SVGSurface("F",12,8))`?

Comment: @IstvanChung Good point.

Answer (score 31):

### HTML + CSS, <s>966 906 843 792</s> 762 bytes

Not a winner anytime, but lots of fun drawing in CSS. This can be golfed a lot though.

**CSS, HTML**:

```css
*{position:fixed}a{background:linear-gradient(0deg,#003478 50%,#C60C30 50%);width:2in;height:2in;transform:rotate(.6rad);top:1in;left:2in}d,e{width:50%;height:50%;background:#C60C30;left:0;top:25%}a,d,e{border-radius:50%}d{background:#003478;left:50%}b,i{width:1in;height:26em;top:-1em;left:15em;transform:rotate(.98rad)}g,f,k,j{width:1in;height:17%;background:repeating-linear-gradient(0deg,#000,#000 1em,#fff 1em,#fff 1.5em);bottom:0;left:0}g,j,p{top:-.5em}b{transform:rotate(-.98rad)}c,p,v,x{height:2em;width:.5em;background:#fff;transform:rotate(.98rad)}p{top:2.8in;left:28em;transform:rotate(-.98rad) scale(1,4)}x{top:3.9em;left:28.4em}c,v{top:23.8em;transform:none}c{top:3.5em}body{height:4in;width:6in;border:1px solid
```

```html
<a><d><e></a><b><f><g></b><i><j><k></i><p></p><x><v><c
```

`;border:1px solid` is just for show as the `<body>` tag has clear boundaries which can be observed by Inspector or similar tools, as stated by the OP

**NOTE** Works only in Firefox (or Chrome canary/dev) due to usage non vendor specific transforms and gradients.

[See it in action](http://codepen.io/scrapmac/pen/uyxfL/left/?editors=010)

Comment: I think you should include <link> or <style> tags in your character count. You can save few characters: in CSS `0deg` -> `0` (twice) and remove `left:0` from `a:before`. In HTML you could use `<p><ul></ul>`. (`<p>` will be implicitly closed before `<ul>`)

Comment: Works in Firefox 32. Fails spectacularly in Safari 7.1.

Comment: Use LESS or SASS for the CSS which should give you quite a lot of options to shorten it quite a bit. Additionally `:before{content:''}` and `:after{content:''}` are longer than just adding another element (despite this indeed looking better).

Comment: @DavidMulder I wanted the fun factor in this rather than shorter code. People can related to pure CSS more easily than LESS or SASS :)

Comment: Works in latest Chrome as well. @200_success You should be able to get it working in Safari by adding `-webkit-` before all the `transform:`s, but [needless to say](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/203836/45199) that would make it quite a bit longer!

Comment: Failing miserably in Chrome 38 on iOS 8.1

Answer (score 21):

## BBC Basic, <s>349</s> 343 ASCII characters, tokenised file size 330

Download emulator at http://www.bbcbasic.co.uk/bbcwin/bbcwin.html

```
  p=1049q=25r=100VDU4118;275;-1,49,3076;19,7,-1;-1;531;255;7693;q;40;0;q,97,1200;800;29,640;400;
  FORa=38TO56STEP0.01x=r*COS(a)y=r*SIN(a)b=a*7DIV44/2IFb=3.5z=y<0ELSEz=x>0
  VDU18;1,p;-x;-y;q,153,r;0;18;2,p;x;y;q,153,r;0;18;0
  IFABS(y)DIV1=56VDUp;x*b+y;y*b-x;q;x/3;y/3;q,113,-2*y;2*x;18;7:b-=0.1VDUp;x*b+y/12;y*b-x/12;q;x/2;y/2;q,112-z,-y/6;x/6;
  NEXT
```

Using the correct colours added a lot, but golfing all the graphics commands down to raw VDU codes gives a saving of 6 characters overall compared with my original post. All graphics on the BBC micro is done via machine-specific ASCII control codes, so instead of using high-level graphics commands you can feed bytes direct to the VDU controller (generally shorter but at great expense to readability). A value ending in semicolon instead of comma is a 16-bit little-endian representation of 2 bytes.

**Ungolfed version**

```
  MODE16
  VDU19,1,-1,49,4,12                :REM adjust shade of red 
  VDU19,7,-1,-1,-1,-1               :REM adjust shade of white to full brightness (63 is 2's complement representation of -1
  VDU19,4,-1,0,13,30                :REM adjust shade of blue
  RECTANGLEFILL40,0,1200,800        :REM plot background rectangle
  ORIGIN640,400
  FORa=38TO56STEP0.01
    x=COS(a)*100
    y=SIN(a)*100
    GCOL1:CIRCLEFILL-x,-y,100       :REM red
    GCOL4:CIRCLEFILLx,y,100         :REM blue
    GCOL0                           :REM black
    b=a*7DIV44/2                    :REM divide a by 2*(22/7) to get integer representation, then divide by 2 again.
    IFb=3.5THENz=y<0ELSEz=x>0       :REM decide whether to cut bar
    REM If the angle is correct (100*sin(a) = 56) draw bar. If required, cut out the middle of the bar.
    IFABS(INT(y))=56 MOVEx*b+y,y*b-x:MOVEBY x/3,y/3:PLOT113,-2*y,2*x:GCOL7:b-=0.1:MOVEx*b+y/12,y*b-x/12:MOVEBY x/2,y/2:IFz PLOT113,-y/6,x/6
  NEXT
```

At the beginning of the program I move the origin to the centre of the screen.

I don't draw any large coloured half circles. Instead I run a loop that draws small red and blue circles, spinning in an anticlockwise direction. I do nearly 3 complete revolutions (starting with blue at the right) which is obviously more than enough to fill in the disc. I stop on the 3rd revolution, just when the blue at lower right is in the correct position to line up with the bars (which have to be plotted.)

When the angle is right, I draw one of the bars. the vector x,y for drawing the current small blue circle serves to tell in which direction the bar should be. For each of the 3 revolutions, a different value of the integer `a*7DIV44` is calculated, which tells whether the first, second or third bar should be drawn, with its inner edge 6/8,7/8 or 8/8 units from the centre (according to the units used in the question spec.) Because the program units are 1/4 of those in the spec, this is still a half-unit, so we divide by 2 again before saving to variable ´b´ to avoid repeated halving later.

The bars are drawn solid, then the middle is deleted if necessary. This prevents kinks from joining half-bars. The variable z indicates if a bar should be cut. That is, when y is negative for the middle bars and when x is positive for the other bars.

`MOVE` is an absolute move. `MOVEBY` is a relative move. `PLOT133` considers the last two graphics cursor positions, plus the new one specified (in relative coordinates) as three corners of a parallelogram, and plots that parallelogram.

**Output (& discussion of language limitations)**

I selected a screen mode of 1280x800 logical pixels = 640x400 physical pixels, which by default has a black background. Onto this I draw a white rectangle from -600,-400 to 600,400 to act as my "canvas."

BBC Basic can handle 16 colours at once, from a reprogrammable pallete. But it only supports 18-bit colour, whereas the question specifies the colours as 24-bit. The colours as close as possible.

[image]

Comment: I've reworded the spec regarding the boundary a bit. The way you handled it is pretty much as I intended it.

Answer (score 16):

## Python 3 turtle (<strike>552</strike> 549 bytes)

[image: Flag]

*([Full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iC4z.png))*

**Edit:** Now that we have Stack Snippets, here's a Stack Snippet test using [Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/), with the help of ArtOfCode's answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40127/21487). Unfortunately, Skulpt hasn't fully implemented Python yet, so I had to mutilate half my code to get this to work. In other words, this snippet is only meant to indicate *how* my program works (without needing to pull up Python).

*(Also, I'm finding that this might not actually work on some browsers...)*

```js
function out(a){var b=document.getElementById("output");b.innerHTML+=a}function builtinRead(a){if(void 0===Sk.builtinFiles||void 0===Sk.builtinFiles.files[a])throw"File not found: '"+a+"'";return Sk.builtinFiles.files[a]}
$(document).ready(function run(){Sk.canvas="canvas";Sk.configure({output:out,read:builtinRead});try{Sk.importMainWithBody("<stdin>",!1,'import turtle\nimport math\nt=turtle.Turtle()\nt.speed(9)\nR="#c60c30"\nr=56.3\nk=0.6\ns=60*k\noffsetx,offsety=-215,-145\nt.up()\nt.goto(offsetx,offsety)\nt.down()\ndef q():t.rt(90)\ndef Q():t.lt(90)\ndef K():t.color("black");t.begin_fill();q()\ndef A(g,G):t.fd(g);Q();t.fd(G);Q();t.fd(g);Q();t.fd(G);Q()\ndef E():t.up();t.fd(s);t.down();Q();t.end_fill();t.up();t.fd(30*k);t.down();\ndef i():K();t.up();t.bk(s);t.down();A(120*k,20*k);E()\ndef I():K();t.up();t.fd(5*k);t.down();A(55*k,20*k);t.up();t.bk(65*k);t.down();A(55*k,20*k);E()\ndef C():t.circle(120*k,180)\nA(720*k,480*k)\nt.seth(r)\nt.up()\nt.goto(459.8*k+offsetx,173.4*k+offsety)\nt.down()\nt.color(R)\nt.begin_fill()\nC()\nt.end_fill()\nt.begin_fill()\nt.color("#003478")\nC()\nt.circle(s)\nt.end_fill()\nt.color(R)\nC()\nt.begin_fill()\nt.circle(s)\nt.end_fill()\nq()\nt.up()\nt.fd(s)\nt.down()\ni()\ni()\ni()\nt.up()\nt.bk(530*k)\nt.down()\nI()\nI()\nI()\nt.up()\nt.fd(170*k)\nt.rt(2*r)\nt.fd(180*k)\nt.down()\nI()\ni()\nI()\nt.up()\nt.bk(530*k)\nt.down()\ni()\nI()\ni()\n')}catch(a){throw Error(a.toString());}})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="http://www.skulpt.org/static/skulpt.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="http://www.skulpt.org/static/skulpt-stdlib.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<canvas height="320" width="480" id="canvas" style="border:1px solid gray">Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas!</canvas>
```

---

Actual code:

```
import turtle as t
b=t.begin_fill
c=t.circle
e=t.end_fill
f=t.fillcolor
R="#c60c30"
r=56.3
F=t.fd
B=t.bk
s=60
def q():t.rt(90)
def Q():t.lt(90)
def K():f(0,0,0);b();q()
def A(g,G):exec("F(g);Q();F(G);Q();"*2)
def E():F(s);Q();e();F(30)
def i():K();B(s);A(120,20);E()
def I():K();F(5);A(55,20);B(65);A(55,20);E()
def C():c(120,180)
A(720,480)
t.seth(r)
t.up()
t.goto(459.8,173.4)
f(R)
b()
C()
e()
b()
f("#003478")
C()
c(s)
e()
C()
f(R)
b()
c(s)
e()
q()
F(s)
i()
i()
i()
B(530)
I()
I()
I()
F(170)
t.rt(2*r)
F(180)
I()
i()
I()
B(530)
i()
I()
i()
t.ht()
```

Since the turtle's such a slowpoke, if you want instant results you can add `t.tracer(0)` after the first line before you run the script.

*Note: For some reason turtle keeps drawing what looks like extra black pixels even though I've already called `up()`, and I have no idea why...*

Comment: I believe someone implemented Python (with turtle!) on the Stack Snippets post; if you wanted to figure out how, you could be one of the first to use this new feature! ;)

Comment: @Doorknob I had to destroy half my code to get it to even vaguely do what I wanted, but at least it visually does the same thing as in Python now. (But it doesn't work on my Chrome for some reason...)

Comment: Working fine on Chrome iOS. Glad to see someone's found a use for my project though :)

Answer (score 14):

### HTML + ES6, 388

```html
<canvas id=D width=576 height=384><script>c=D.getContext('2d')
T=x=>c.translate(x*72,x*48)
R=(x,y)=>T(4)+c.rotate(x*.59)+T(-4)+eval('for(i=j=0;i*j<6;i+=(j^=1))c.fillRect(72+24*i+(i>2)*288,144+j*52,16,44+52*(y>>i&1-j))')
A=(w,x,y,z)=>(c.fillStyle=c.fill()+c.beginPath()||w)*c.arc(x*4,192-y,48*y,0,3.1,z)||A
R(-1,21)
R(2,7)
A(r='#C60C30',72,2,1)('#003478',72,2)(0,84,1,1)(r,60,1)()</script>
```

If your browser supports ES6, you can [view it on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grc4/kk2afn80/10/) or run the snippet.

It constructs the flag out of some basic shapes, rotating the canvas first to account for the angles.

Comment: Just a note this doesn't work in Chrome 39, works fine in FF > 29.

Comment: `<canvas width=576 height=384 id=D><script>c=D.getContext('2d')` is 9 bytes less. Also, since the whole page is white, I think you need to draw the border.

Comment: @Optimizer Thanks. As I understand it, the border is only needed when you have an infinite canvas.

Comment: You could try this with Stack Snippets!

Comment: @BetaDecay it actually worked :o

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica <s>404</s> 450

```
b=1&~Array~13;a=ReplacePart[b,7-> 0];d=Disk;r=RGBColor;
z@{q_,p_,s_}:=ArrayPlot[{q,q,{},p,p,{},s,s},Frame-> False,ImageSize-> 155];
m=r@@{0,.2,.5};
o=r@@{.8,0,.2};
t=-19.1;u=-12.75;v=-5;q=-3.33;
Graphics[{Line[{{-36,-24},{36,-24},{36,24},{-36,24},{-36,-24}}],
Inset[Rotate[z@#,#2 125 Degree],#3]&@@@{{{b,a,b},1,{t,u}},{{a,b,a},1,{-t,-u}},
{{a,a,a},-1,{-t,u}},{{b,b,b},-1,{t,-u}}},
{o,d[{0,0},12,{-.2 Pi,.8Pi}],m, d[{0,0},12,{.8Pi,1.8Pi}],o,d[{v,-q},6],m,d[{-v,q},6]}}]
```

[image: flag]

Answer (score 3):

## C++ TOO LARGE

Attempted this using my home made [PPM drawing library](http://myweb.uiowa.edu/stcrowle/Files/PPMDraw.zip). It's technically scalable, but I'm limited by my recursive fill function because it's unreliable and likes to segfault, I think it's using up too much memory, so I won't actually let the user set the scale. The image is irregular because the coordinates I entered for each corner of the bars are slightly off.
[image]

I set it up to start with a black background, then put a white circle in the middle, then red and blue circles in that. Used recursive fills to add the rest of red and blue. Then drew rectangles with white lines to mark the black bars. Split the black background into 4 sections with white lines and used 4 recursive fills to make each section white. Doing it in 1 pass would have caused a segfault. It's still very slow to render.

### Ungolfed main code ( the rest of the library is too large, golfing this doesn't matter )

```
#include "PPMDraw.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "Drawing Korean Flag" << std::endl;

    int scale = 150;
    int width = 3 * scale;
    int height = 2 * scale;

    int xc = width/2;
    int yc = height/2;

    // coords for the bar corners
    float nwax = -0.773; float nway = -0.813;
    float nwbx = -0.707; float nwby = -0.773;
    float nwcx = -1.000; float nwcy = -0.360;
    float nwdx = -1.050; float nwdy = -0.400;
    float nwex = -0.667; float nwey = -0.747;
    float nwfx = -0.613; float nwfy = -0.693;
    float nwgx = -0.880; float nwgy = -0.293;
    float nwhx = -0.947; float nwhy = -0.333;
    float nwix = -0.560; float nwiy = -0.667;
    float nwjx = -0.507; float nwjy = -0.627;
    float nwkx = -0.773; float nwky = -0.227;
    float nwlx = -0.840; float nwly = -0.267;

    float neax = 0.747; float neay = -0.813;
    float nebx = 0.867; float neby = -0.627;
    float necx = 0.813; float necy = -0.587;
    float nedx = 0.680; float nedy = -0.773;
    float neex = 0.893; float neey = -0.587;
    float nefx = 1.030; float nefy = -0.400;
    float negx = 0.960; float negy = -0.360;
    float nehx = 0.840; float nehy = -0.547;
    float neix = 0.640; float neiy = -0.747;
    float nejx = 0.920; float nejy = -0.333;
    float nekx = 0.853; float neky = -0.293;
    float nelx = 0.587; float nely = -0.693;
    float nemx = 0.533; float nemy = -0.667;
    float nenx = 0.667; float neny = -0.493;
    float neox = 0.600; float neoy = -0.440;
    float nepx = 0.480; float nepy = -0.627;
    float neqx = 0.693; float neqy = -0.440;
    float nerx = 0.813; float nery = -0.267;
    float nesx = 0.747; float nesy = -0.227;
    float netx = 0.627; float nety = -0.400;

    float swax = -0.773; float sway = 0.200;
    float swbx = -0.507; float swby = 0.613;
    float swcx = -0.560; float swcy = 0.653;
    float swdx = -0.840; float swdy = 0.253;
    float swex = -0.880; float swey = 0.280;
    float swfx = -0.760; float swfy = 0.453;
    float swgx = -0.813; float swgy = 0.493;
    float swhx = -0.947; float swhy = 0.320;
    float swix = -0.733; float swiy = 0.507;
    float swjx = -0.613; float swjy = 0.680;
    float swkx = -0.667; float swky = 0.720;
    float swlx = -0.787; float swly = 0.547;
    float swmx = -0.987; float swmy = 0.347;
    float swnx = -0.707; float swny = 0.760;
    float swox = -0.773; float swoy = 0.800;
    float swpx = -1.053; float swpy = 0.387;

    float seax = 0.747; float seay = 0.200;
    float sebx = 0.813; float seby = 0.253;
    float secx = 0.693; float secy = 0.427;
    float sedx = 0.627; float sedy = 0.387;
    float seex = 0.853; float seey = 0.280;
    float sefx = 0.920; float sefy = 0.320;
    float segx = 0.800; float segy = 0.507;
    float sehx = 0.733; float sehy = 0.453;
    float seix = 0.960; float seiy = 0.347;
    float sejx = 1.036; float sejy = 0.387;
    float sekx = 0.893; float seky = 0.573;
    float selx = 0.840; float sely = 0.520;
    float semx = 0.600; float semy = 0.427;
    float senx = 0.667; float seny = 0.467;
    float seox = 0.547; float seoy = 0.653;
    float sepx = 0.480; float sepy = 0.613;
    float seqx = 0.707; float seqy = 0.493;
    float serx = 0.773; float sery = 0.547;
    float sesx = 0.640; float sesy = 0.733;
    float setx = 0.547; float sety = 0.680;
    float seux = 0.813; float seuy = 0.573;
    float sevx = 0.880; float sevy = 0.613;
    float sewx = 0.747; float sewy = 0.800;
    float sexx = 0.693; float sexy = 0.747;

    PPMDraw flag = PPMDraw(width, height);
    flag.fill(0, 0, 0);

    // draw white circle in middle
    flag.set_color(255, 255, 255);
    flag.draw_fill_circle(xc, yc, scale/2);

    // draw red and blue portions of circle
    flag.set_color(255, 0, 0);
    flag.draw_fill_circle(xc - .21*scale, yc - .14*scale, scale/3.9);
    flag.set_color(0, 0, 255);
    flag.draw_fill_circle(xc + .21*scale, yc + .14*scale, scale/3.9);
    flag.set_color(255, 0, 0);
    flag.recursive_fill(xc + .21*scale, yc - .21*scale);
    flag.set_color(0, 0, 255);
    flag.recursive_fill(xc - .21*scale, yc + .21*scale);

    // draw the northwest bars
    flag.set_color(255, 255, 255);

    flag.draw_line(xc + nwax*scale, yc + nway*scale, xc + nwbx*scale, yc + nwby*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + nwax*scale, yc + nway*scale, xc + nwdx*scale, yc + nwdy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + nwbx*scale, yc + nwby*scale, xc + nwcx*scale, yc + nwcy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + nwcx*scale, yc + nwcy*scale, xc + nwdx*scale, yc + nwdy*scale);

    flag.draw_line(xc + nwex*scale, yc + nwey*scale, xc + nwfx*scale, yc + nwfy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + nwex*scale, yc + nwey*scale, xc + nwhx*scale, yc + nwhy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + nwfx*scale, yc + nwfy*scale, xc + nwgx*scale, yc + nwgy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + nwhx*scale, yc + nwhy*scale, xc + nwgx*scale, yc + nwgy*scale);

    flag.draw_line(xc + nwix*scale, yc + nwiy*scale, xc + nwjx*scale, yc + nwjy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + nwix*scale, yc + nwiy*scale, xc + nwlx*scale, yc + nwly*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + nwjx*scale, yc + nwjy*scale, xc + nwkx*scale, yc + nwky*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + nwlx*scale, yc + nwly*scale, xc + nwkx*scale, yc + nwky*scale);
    //NE
    flag.draw_line(xc + neax*scale, yc + neay*scale, xc + nebx*scale, yc + neby*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + neax*scale, yc + neay*scale, xc + nedx*scale, yc + nedy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + nebx*scale, yc + neby*scale, xc + necx*scale, yc + necy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + necx*scale, yc + necy*scale, xc + nedx*scale, yc + nedy*scale);

    flag.draw_line(xc + neex*scale, yc + neey*scale, xc + nefx*scale, yc + nefy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + neex*scale, yc + neey*scale, xc + nehx*scale, yc + nehy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + nefx*scale, yc + nefy*scale, xc + negx*scale, yc + negy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + nehx*scale, yc + nehy*scale, xc + negx*scale, yc + negy*scale);

    flag.draw_line(xc + neix*scale, yc + neiy*scale, xc + nejx*scale, yc + nejy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + neix*scale, yc + neiy*scale, xc + nelx*scale, yc + nely*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + nejx*scale, yc + nejy*scale, xc + nekx*scale, yc + neky*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + nelx*scale, yc + nely*scale, xc + nekx*scale, yc + neky*scale);

    flag.draw_line(xc + nemx*scale, yc + nemy*scale, xc + nenx*scale, yc + neny*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + nemx*scale, yc + nemy*scale, xc + nepx*scale, yc + nepy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + nepx*scale, yc + nepy*scale, xc + neox*scale, yc + neoy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + nenx*scale, yc + neny*scale, xc + neox*scale, yc + neoy*scale);

    flag.draw_line(xc + neqx*scale, yc + neqy*scale, xc + nerx*scale, yc + nery*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + neqx*scale, yc + neqy*scale, xc + netx*scale, yc + nety*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + nerx*scale, yc + nery*scale, xc + nesx*scale, yc + nesy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + netx*scale, yc + nety*scale, xc + nesx*scale, yc + nesy*scale);

    //sw
    flag.draw_line(xc + swax*scale, yc + sway*scale, xc + swbx*scale, yc + swby*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + swax*scale, yc + sway*scale, xc + swdx*scale, yc + swdy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + swbx*scale, yc + swby*scale, xc + swcx*scale, yc + swcy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + swcx*scale, yc + swcy*scale, xc + swdx*scale, yc + swdy*scale);

    flag.draw_line(xc + swex*scale, yc + swey*scale, xc + swfx*scale, yc + swfy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + swex*scale, yc + swey*scale, xc + swhx*scale, yc + swhy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + swfx*scale, yc + swfy*scale, xc + swgx*scale, yc + swgy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + swhx*scale, yc + swhy*scale, xc + swgx*scale, yc + swgy*scale);

    flag.draw_line(xc + swix*scale, yc + swiy*scale, xc + swjx*scale, yc + swjy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + swix*scale, yc + swiy*scale, xc + swlx*scale, yc + swly*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + swjx*scale, yc + swjy*scale, xc + swkx*scale, yc + swky*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + swlx*scale, yc + swly*scale, xc + swkx*scale, yc + swky*scale);

    flag.draw_line(xc + swmx*scale, yc + swmy*scale, xc + swnx*scale, yc + swny*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + swmx*scale, yc + swmy*scale, xc + swpx*scale, yc + swpy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + swpx*scale, yc + swpy*scale, xc + swox*scale, yc + swoy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + swnx*scale, yc + swny*scale, xc + swox*scale, yc + swoy*scale);

    //se
    flag.draw_line(xc + seax*scale, yc + seay*scale, xc + sebx*scale, yc + seby*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + seax*scale, yc + seay*scale, xc + sedx*scale, yc + sedy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + sebx*scale, yc + seby*scale, xc + secx*scale, yc + secy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + secx*scale, yc + secy*scale, xc + sedx*scale, yc + sedy*scale);

    flag.draw_line(xc + seex*scale, yc + seey*scale, xc + sefx*scale, yc + sefy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + seex*scale, yc + seey*scale, xc + sehx*scale, yc + sehy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + sefx*scale, yc + sefy*scale, xc + segx*scale, yc + segy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + sehx*scale, yc + sehy*scale, xc + segx*scale, yc + segy*scale);

    flag.draw_line(xc + seix*scale, yc + seiy*scale, xc + sejx*scale, yc + sejy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + seix*scale, yc + seiy*scale, xc + selx*scale, yc + sely*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + sejx*scale, yc + sejy*scale, xc + sekx*scale, yc + seky*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + selx*scale, yc + sely*scale, xc + sekx*scale, yc + seky*scale);

    flag.draw_line(xc + semx*scale, yc + semy*scale, xc + senx*scale, yc + seny*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + semx*scale, yc + semy*scale, xc + sepx*scale, yc + sepy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + sepx*scale, yc + sepy*scale, xc + seox*scale, yc + seoy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + senx*scale, yc + seny*scale, xc + seox*scale, yc + seoy*scale);

    flag.draw_line(xc + seqx*scale, yc + seqy*scale, xc + serx*scale, yc + sery*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + seqx*scale, yc + seqy*scale, xc + setx*scale, yc + sety*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + serx*scale, yc + sery*scale, xc + sesx*scale, yc + sesy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + setx*scale, yc + sety*scale, xc + sesx*scale, yc + sesy*scale);

    flag.draw_line(xc + seux*scale, yc + seuy*scale, xc + sevx*scale, yc + sevy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + seux*scale, yc + seuy*scale, xc + sexx*scale, yc + sexy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + sevx*scale, yc + sevy*scale, xc + sewx*scale, yc + sewy*scale);
    flag.draw_line(xc + sexx*scale, yc + sexy*scale, xc + sewx*scale, yc + sewy*scale);

    // fill in the black to white
    flag.draw_line(xc, yc - scale/2, xc, 0);
    flag.draw_line(xc, yc + scale/2, xc, height);
    flag.draw_line(xc - scale/2, yc, 0, yc);
    flag.draw_line(xc + scale/2, yc, width, yc);

    flag.recursive_fill(0, 0);
    flag.recursive_fill(0, height-1);
    flag.recursive_fill(width - 1, 0);
    flag.recursive_fill(width - 1, height - 1);

    flag.save("flag.ppm");

}
```

Comment: @SohamChowdhury Totally unintentional, SEXY is SouthEast corner, Point X, Y coordinate.

Comment: Yours is the only solution where the flag is waving in the wind!

Answer (score 3):

## [PostScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript), <s>572</s> <s>477</s> 471 bytes

Golfed code:

```postscript
5 5 scale 36 24 translate<</R{.75 .05 .19 setrgbcolor}/B{0 .20 .47 setrgbcolor}/a 2 3 atan/b{0 setgray[18 -6 2 12 21 -6 2 12 24 -6 2 12]rectfill 1 setgray{[18 -.5 2 1 24 -.5 2 1]rectfill}if{21 -.5 2 1 rectfill}if}>>begin a neg rotate R 0 0 12 0 180 arc closepath fill B 0 0 12 180 0 arc closepath fill R -6 0 6 0 360 arc closepath fill B 6 0 6 0 360 arc closepath fill true true b 2 a mul rotate false true b 180 rotate true false b -2 a mul rotate false false b showpage
```

Ungolfed code:

```postscript
5 5 scale                                     % over-all scale
36 24 translate                               % over-all shift

% define some short-named procedures for later use
<<
  /R {.75 .05 .19 setrgbcolor}                % prodecure for setting red color
  /B {0 .20 .47 setrgbcolor}                  % procedure for setting blue color
  /a 2 3 atan                                 % calculate angle = arctan(2/3) = 33.7°
  /b {                                        % procedure for drawing bars
    0 setgray                                    %   black
    [18 -6 2 12 21 -6 2 12 24 -6 2 12] rectfill  %   draw 3 bars
    1 setgray                                    %   white
    {[18 -.5 2 1 24 -.5 2 1] rectfill} if        %   conditionally draw gap in inner/outer bars 
    {21 -.5 2 1 rectfill} if                     %   conditionally draw gap in middle bar 
  }
>> begin

a neg rotate                                  % rotate -33.7°
R 0 0 12 0 180 arc closepath fill             % big red half circle
B 0 0 12 180 0 arc closepath fill             % big blue half circle
R -6 0 6 0 360 arc closepath fill             % small red circle
B  6 0 6 0 360 arc closepath fill             % small blue circle
true true b                                   % draw bars (with gap in all bars)
2 a mul rotate                                % rotate 67.4°
false true b                                  % draw bars (with gap in inner/outer bars)
180 rotate                                    % rotate 180°
true false b                                  % draw bars (with gap in middle bar)
-2 a mul rotate                               % rotate -67.4°
false false b                                 % draw bars (without gaps)
showpage
```

Result (as animation to see how it is drawn):

[image: result]

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 31 bytes

```
"SouthKorea"~CountryData~"Flag"
```

[image]

Comment:  Mathematica always feels a bit like cheating...

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 483 bytes

```python
from math import*
w,k,r,b="255 "*3,"0 "*3,"198 12 48 ","0 52 120 "
print "P3 600 400 255 "
a=atan2(2,3)
c,s=cos(a),sin(a)
T=lambda x,y:(c*x-s*y,s*x+c*y)
S=lambda x,y:150<x<216.6and x%25<16.6and y*y<2500
C=lambda x,y,p=50:(x-p)**2+y*y<2500
for y in range(-200,200):
 for x in range(-300,300):X,Y=T(x,y);W,Z=T(-x,y);print [[w,k][(S(abs(X),Y)and(Y*Y>16or(166.6<X<191.4or-200>X or 0>X>-166.6)))or(S(abs(W),Z)and(W>0 or abs(Z)>4))],[b,r][(Z<0 or C(W,Z))and not C(W,Z,-50)]][W*W+Z*Z<10000]
```

Possible improvements:

- hardcode the cos,sin constants
- binary PPM
- transform to [3,2] plane
- optimize the boolean statements

Output as text PPM, usage:

```python
python golf_korea.py > korea.ppm
```

[image]

#### ungolfed beta version

```python
from math import*
w,k,r,b="255 255 255 ", "0 0 0 ", "255 0 0 ", "0 0 255 "
g="0 255 0 "
print "P3 600 400 255 "
a=atan2(2,3)
c,s=cos(a),sin(a)
trans=lambda x,y:(c*x-s*y,s*x+c*y)
stripe=lambda x:150<x<216.6 and x%25<16.6
small=lambda x,y,p=50:(x-p)**2+y*y<2500
for y in range(-200,200):
 for x in range(-300,300):
  X,Y=trans(x,y)
  W,Z=trans(-x,y)
  if stripe(abs(X)) and Y*Y<2500:
   if abs(Y)>4:  
    print k
   else:
    if X>0:
     if 166.6<X<191.4:
      print k
     else:
      print w
    else:
     if -200<X<-166.6:
      print w
     else:
      print k
  elif stripe(abs(W)) and Z*Z<2500 and(W>0 or abs(Z)>4):
   print k
  elif W*W+Z*Z<100*100:
   if (Z<0 or small(W,Z)) and not small(W,Z,-50):
    print r
   else:
    print b
  else:
   print w
```