# I-Ching pair binary computer

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, binary, unicode

#### Introduction

[I Ching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Ching) is an ancient divination text and the oldest of the Chinese classics. It uses a type of divination called cleromancy, which produces apparently random numbers.

The basic unit of the Zhou yi is the [hexagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hexagrams_of_the_I_Ching) (卦 guà), a figure composed of six stacked horizontal lines (爻 yáo). Each line is either broken or unbroken. The received text of the Zhou yi contains all 64 possible [hexagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hexagrams_of_the_I_Ching)

The [King Wen sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Wen_sequence) present the 64 hexagrams, grouped into 32 pairs. For 28 of the pairs, the second hexagram is created by turning the first upside down (i.e. 180° rotation). The exception to this rule is for symmetrical hexagrams that are the same after rotation. Partners for these are given by inverting each line: solid becomes broken and broken becomes solid.

> ```
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄      ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄      ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄      ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄      ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄      ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄      ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>     1        2        3        4            5        6        7        8   
>
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄      ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄      ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄      ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄      ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄      ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄      ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>     9       10       11       12           13       14       15       16   
>
>  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄      ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄      ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄      ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄      ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄      ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄      ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
>    17       18       19       20           21       22       23       24   
>
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄      ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄      ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄      ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄      ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄      ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄      ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>    25       26       27       28           29       30       31       32   
>
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄      ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄      ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄      ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄      ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄      ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄      ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>    33       34       35       36           37       38       39       40   
>
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄      ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄      ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄      ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄      ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄      ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄      ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>    41       42       43       44           45       46       47       48   
>
>  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄      ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄      ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄      ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄      ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄      ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄      ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>    49       50       51       52           53       54       55       56   
>
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄      ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄      ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄      ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄      ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄      ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
>  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄      ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
>    57       58       59       60           61       62       63       64
> ```

#### Request

The goal of this is to create a little tool that compute pair for a given hexagram value.

- For translating this into binary, I use: `broken line = 0,  unbroken line = 1`, so *`hexagram Number 1`* has *`binary value 63`*.
- The tool take exactly one argument, a number between 1 to 64, as hexagram pair request and produce two exagram containing requested number and his *oposite* (explanation: if arg is odd, the output must contain hexagram from *arg* and *arg + 1*, but if arg is even, the output must contain hexagram from *arg - 1* and *arg*).
- The tool have to *rotate* by 180° requested hexagram while **not symetric**, **or** invert them when **symetric**.
- No map are authorized except this one, wich could be stored in any form you'll find usefull

  ```
   {  1:63,    3:34,    5:58,    7:16,    9:59,   11:56,   13:47,   15: 8,  
     17:38,   19:48,   21:37,   23: 1,   25:39,   27:33,   29:18,   31:14,  
     33:15,   35: 5,   37:43,   39:10,   41:49,   43:62,   45: 6,   47:22,  
     49:46,   51:36,   53:11,   55:44,   57:27,   59:19,   61:51,   63:42 }
  ```

  This map hold *binary* value of each 1st exagram from pairs.
  So for each pair, 1st has to be taken from this map, but second have to be computed conforming to previous rule.
- Ouput must contain two hexagram and his numbers. Sample:

  ```
  iChingHexaPair 1
   ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
   ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
   ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
   ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
   ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
   ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
      1        2   

  iChingHexaPair 14
   ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
   ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
   ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
   ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
   ▄▄▄ ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
   ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
     13       14
  ```
- Standard loophole applies
- Please avoid non-free language or post output for full test cases.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in **characters** wins.

#### Shortest by language

```html
<style>body { text-align: left !important} #answer-list { padding: 10px; width: 290px; float: left; } #language-list { padding: 10px; width: 290px; float: left; } table thead { font-weight: bold; } table td { padding: 5px; }</style><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="language-list"> <h2>Shortest Solution by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr> </thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr> </thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr> </tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr> </tbody> </table><script>var QUESTION_ID = document.referrer.split("/")[4]; var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe"; var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk"; var OVERRIDE_USER = 0; var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page; function answersUrl(index) { return "//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" + QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER; } function commentUrl(index, answers) { return "//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER; } function getAnswers() { jQuery.ajax({ url: answersUrl(answer_page++), method: "get", dataType: "jsonp", crossDomain: true, success: function (data) { answers.push.apply(answers, data.items); answers_hash = []; answer_ids = []; data.items.forEach(function(a) { a.comments = []; var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/); answer_ids.push(id); answers_hash[id] = a; }); if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false; comment_page = 1; getComments(); } }); } function getComments() { jQuery.ajax({ url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids), method: "get", dataType: "jsonp", crossDomain: true, success: function (data) { data.items.forEach(function(c) { if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER) answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c); }); if (data.has_more) getComments(); else if (more_answers) getAnswers(); else process(); } }); } getAnswers(); var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,<]*(?:<(?:[^\n>]*>[^\n<]*<\/[^\n>]*>)[^\n,<]*)*),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/; var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i; function getAuthorName(a) { return a.owner.display_name; } function process() { var valid = []; answers.forEach(function(a) { var body = a.body; a.comments.forEach(function(c) { if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body)) body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>'; }); var match = body.match(SCORE_REG); if (match) valid.push({ user: getAuthorName(a), size: +match[2], language: match[1], link: a.share_link, }); else console.log(body); }); valid.sort(function (a, b) { var aB = a.size, bB = b.size; return aB - bB }); var languages = {}; var place = 1; var lastSize = null; var lastPlace = 1; valid.forEach(function (a) { if (a.size != lastSize) lastPlace = place; lastSize = a.size; ++place; var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html(); answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".") .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user) .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language) .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size) .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link); answer = jQuery(answer); jQuery("#answers").append(answer); var lang = a.language; lang = jQuery('<a>'+lang+'</a>').text(); languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, lang_raw: lang.toLowerCase(42), user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link}; }); var langs = []; for (var lang in languages) if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang)) langs.push(languages[lang]); langs.sort(function (a, b) { if (a.lang_raw > b.lang_raw) return 1; if (a.lang_raw < b.lang_raw) return -1; return 0; }); for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i) { var language = jQuery("#language-template").html(); var lang = langs[i]; language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang) .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user) .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size) .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link); language = jQuery(language); jQuery("#languages").append(language); } }</script>
```

Comment: [Vaguely related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/40052/8478)

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yes, thanks! Maybe could we add a tag: [tag:I-Ching] (I did not foud them while searched for I-Ching, hexagram and so) But my question if more about *`rotating binary by 180°`*

Comment: Note that currently the standard loophole regarding non-free languages applies only to [tag:cops-and-robbers] challenges.

Comment: @AlexA.Question modified: *non-free* language are not welcome but not forbiden, Output sample are required for *non-free* languages.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, <s>65</s> 61

Generates unicode I-Ching hexagram pairs

```
def t(a):
 b=a+a%2
 for c in b-1,b:
  print unichr(19903+c),c
```

(saved 4 thanks to @Sherlock9)

Example input and output:

```
>>> t(1)
䷀ 1
䷁ 2
>>> t(14)
䷌ 13
䷍ 14
```

Comment: I think you can save 4 bytes with `b=a+a%2`

Comment: That's a loophole: there is no binary calculator!

Comment: @F.Hauri: It doesn't say there needs to be one in the question at all.

Comment: @Deusovi  (1) In the title, (2) in the first line of request, (3) At least, it break fourth rule:  *`1st has to be taken from this map`*!

Comment: @F: You say the goal is to compute the pair but then you just have to output the hexagram pairs. The 'table' is built into Unicode instead of in a text file - what's wrong with that?

Comment: @Deusovi I said *The goal is to **compute***!! The table in unicode is **not** the table I submit: It's two time bigger! (and built-in -> loophole!!)

Comment: @F.Hauri I think that this is as valid as any other submission. This does exactly what the question is asking for. Furthermore, you'd be hard-pressed to find a language that wouldn't allow this and isn't an esolang, and therefore doesn't have this Unicode table "built in".

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>252</s> <s>245</s> 244

Now including binary computation (saving 8 chars thanks to @Sherlock9):

```
d='?":\x10;8/\x08&0%\x01\'!\x12\x0e\x0f\x05+\n1>\x06\x16.$\x0b,\x1b\x133*'
k=lambda l:'\n'.join("{:06b}".format(l)).replace('1',u'▄▄▄▄▄▄▄').replace('0',u'▄▄▄ ▄▄▄')
def t(a):
 j=a+a%2-1;m=ord(d[j/2]);b=k(m);r=b[::-1];print b,j,'\n\n',r if r!=b else k(63-m),j+1
```

Example input and output:

```
>>> t(1)
▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
▄▄▄▄▄▄▄ 1 

▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
▄▄▄ ▄▄▄ 2
>>> t(3)
▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
▄▄▄ ▄▄▄ 3 

▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
▄▄▄ ▄▄▄
▄▄▄▄▄▄▄ 4
```

Comment: You can change `j=a+a%2-1` to `j=a-1`, since you're using integer division, but you'll need to use `j+1` and `j+2` in the print statement at the end. That still saves you 2 bytes. Also using `m=ord(d[j/2]);` and `m` in the two places you call `k()` will save 6 bytes. Also, is the first `0` in `"{0:06b}".format(l)` strictly necessary? If not, that's another byte. Finally, if you switch to Python 3, you can get rid of the `u`s in front of `▄▄▄▄▄▄▄`, but print will need parentheses, so that's only one more byte. I'll keep you posted on anything else I think up.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change `j=a+a%2-1` to `j=a-1` as it should output the pairs 13 and 14 when I input 14. Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Ah, you're right. Incidentally, I'm having trouble running this code in Ideone. Can you take a look? http://ideone.com/GdWu4e

Comment: @Sherlock9 Ideone seems to be having problems with the unicode characters http://ideone.com/FeK1rK

Comment: Ah, thanks. To save another byte, I'd write `def t(a):j=a+a%2-1;etc.`. Put it all one line, essentially. And you can write `k=lambda l:` to save another byte.

Answer (score 2):

## Pure bash 252

```
u=(▅▅▅{' ',▅}▅▅▅);m=_yWgXUL8CMB1Dxief5HaN@6mKAbIrjPG;s=$[($1-1)/2];r=$[64#${m:s:1}];for i in {0..5};do echo ${u[(r>>i)&1]} ${u[((r>>5)%2==r%2)&((r>>4)%2==(r>>1)%2)&((r>>3)%2==(r>>2)%2)?1^(r>>i)&1:(r>>(5-i))&1]};done;echo $[s*2+1] $[s*2+2]
```

with 2 more linebreak:

```
u=(▅▅▅{' ',▅}▅▅▅);m=_yWgXUL8CMB1Dxief5HaN@6mKAbIrjPG;s=$[($1-1)/2];r=$[64#${m:s
:1}];for i in {0..5};do echo ${u[(r>>i)&1]} ${u[((r>>5)%2==r%2)&((r>>4)%2==(r>>
1)%2)&((r>>3)%2==(r>>2)%2)?1^(r>>i)&1:(r>>(5-i))&1]};done;echo $[s*2+1] $[s*2+2]
```

Tests:

```
for k in 1 15 28 34;do set -- $k;echo request: $k;
u=(▅▅▅{' ',▅}▅▅▅);m=_yWgXUL8CMB1Dxief5HaN@6mKAbIrjPG;s=$[($1-1)/2];r=$[64#${m:s
:1}];for i in {0..5};do echo ${u[(r>>i)&1]} ${u[((r>>5)%2==r%2)&((r>>4)%2==(r>>
1)%2)&((r>>3)%2==(r>>2)%2)?1^(r>>i)&1:(r>>(5-i))&1]};done;echo $[s*2+1] $[s*2+2]
done;echo $[s*2+1] $[s*2+2]; done
request: 1
▅▅▅▅▅▅▅ ▅▅▅ ▅▅▅
▅▅▅▅▅▅▅ ▅▅▅ ▅▅▅
▅▅▅▅▅▅▅ ▅▅▅ ▅▅▅
▅▅▅▅▅▅▅ ▅▅▅ ▅▅▅
▅▅▅▅▅▅▅ ▅▅▅ ▅▅▅
▅▅▅▅▅▅▅ ▅▅▅ ▅▅▅
1 2
request: 15
▅▅▅ ▅▅▅ ▅▅▅ ▅▅▅
▅▅▅ ▅▅▅ ▅▅▅ ▅▅▅
▅▅▅ ▅▅▅ ▅▅▅▅▅▅▅
▅▅▅▅▅▅▅ ▅▅▅ ▅▅▅
▅▅▅ ▅▅▅ ▅▅▅ ▅▅▅
▅▅▅ ▅▅▅ ▅▅▅ ▅▅▅
15 16
request: 28
▅▅▅▅▅▅▅ ▅▅▅ ▅▅▅
▅▅▅ ▅▅▅ ▅▅▅▅▅▅▅
▅▅▅ ▅▅▅ ▅▅▅▅▅▅▅
▅▅▅ ▅▅▅ ▅▅▅▅▅▅▅
▅▅▅ ▅▅▅ ▅▅▅▅▅▅▅
▅▅▅▅▅▅▅ ▅▅▅ ▅▅▅
27 28
request: 34
▅▅▅▅▅▅▅ ▅▅▅ ▅▅▅
▅▅▅▅▅▅▅ ▅▅▅ ▅▅▅
▅▅▅▅▅▅▅ ▅▅▅▅▅▅▅
▅▅▅▅▅▅▅ ▅▅▅▅▅▅▅
▅▅▅ ▅▅▅ ▅▅▅▅▅▅▅
▅▅▅ ▅▅▅ ▅▅▅▅▅▅▅
33 34
```